# Use org.eclipse cut/copy/paste in custom RCP application

Tags: eclipse, editor, copy, rcp, cut

I am developing a RCP application and I need cut/copy/paste in this app. As there are already commands which are delivered by eclipse (org.eclipse.ui.edit.copy, ...) I want to use them (I already added them to the toolbar, e.g.) in an editor. 
I played around a little, but I don't get it how I can react to the copy/paste command. E.g. how do I get informed in an editor if something was copied or pasted?

Is there an easy way to use the commands like the Save Command. There I just have to implement the ISaveablePart and then the doSave() or doSaveAs() methods are called...I really like this, but I didn't find ICopyablePart,... interfaces ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need specific behaviour to copy (or any command) within your editor or view, you would activate a handler for it.  Usually in your `createPartControl(Composite)` method:

```
IHandlerService serv = (IHandlerService) getSite().getService(IHandlerService.class);
MyCopyHandler cp = new MyCopyHandler(this);
serv.activateHandler(org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchCommandConstants.EDIT_COPY, cp);
```

The other common way is to provide a handler through your plugin.xml:

```
<handler commandId="org.eclipse.ui.edit.copy"
         handler="com.example.app.MyCopyHandler">
   <activeWhen>
      <with variable="activePartId">
         <equals value="com.example.app.MyEditorId"/>
      </with>
   </activeWhen>
</handler>
```

Then in your handler, you would get the active part and call your copy implementation on it.  ex:

```
IWorkbenchPart part = HandlerUtil.getActivePart(event);
if (part instanceof MyEditor) {
    ((MyEditor)part).copy();
}
```

Comment: Hi Paul, I tried it both ways. But I always get this exception: "There is no handler to execute for command org.eclipse.ui.edit.copy." Do you know why I get this?

Comment: Hi Paul, I have solved the problem. It occurs if the isHandled() returnes false... Returning true will call the execute method...

Comment: Try and subclass AbstractHandler instead of implementing IHandler.  It'll behave correctly in most cases then.