# insert text to current text editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am writing a plugin for eclipse and I am stuck at this :

*How to insert text to the current editor at the cursor's place ?*

I'm quite new to eclipse plugin development, and I really do not know where to begin. Example code and further document are appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This and other functionality is already part of Eclipse and can be integrated into your editor. You may find this answer to another question helpful to get started: [use-org-eclipse-cut-copy-paste-in-custom-rcp-aplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081958/use-org-eclipse-cut-copy-paste-in-custom-rcp-aplication)