# Does Eclipse RCP include a built in cut/copy/paste handler?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

As the title says I'm wondering whether Eclipse RCP 4 provides any built in cut/copy/paste handlers which can be linked to the `org.eclipse.ui.edit.cut`, `org.eclipse.ui.edit.copy` and `org.eclipse.ui.edit.paste` commands?

I appreciate that that a custom handler may be needed for some SWT widgets or more complex use cases with cut/copy/paste operations, but I can't help but feel I'm trying to re-invent the wheel to copy some text from one component and paste in into another.

If there aren't any built in cut/copy/paste handlers, are there any well documented examples of how to do this? I understand how to use the `clipboard.getContents` and `clipboard.setContents` methods, but have found this starts to become non-trivial when trying to find out what text was selected when the copy command is invoked and which component has focus and whether its read only when the paste command is invoked.

I've looked at this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081958/use-org-eclipse-cut-copy-paste-in-custom-rcp-aplication) question but it doesn't explain whether there any built in handlers or offer any guidance on writing my own handlers.

Answer (score 3):

For a 3.x compatibilty mode Eclipse 4 application these commands are defined as:

```xml
 <command
        name="%command.cut.name"
        description="%command.cut.description"
        categoryId="org.eclipse.ui.category.edit"
        id="org.eclipse.ui.edit.cut"
        defaultHandler="org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WidgetMethodHandler:cut" />
  <command
        name="%command.copy.name"
        description="%command.copy.description"
        categoryId="org.eclipse.ui.category.edit"
        id="org.eclipse.ui.edit.copy"
        defaultHandler="org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WidgetMethodHandler:copy" />
  <command
        name="%command.paste.name"
        description="%command.paste.description"
        categoryId="org.eclipse.ui.category.edit"
        id="org.eclipse.ui.edit.paste"
        defaultHandler="org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WidgetMethodHandler:paste" />
```

So they all use `org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.WidgetMethodHandler` as the default handler which is used when no other handler is active.

This handler uses reflection to look for the method name `cut`, `copy` or `paste` in the currently focussed SWT Widget and calls that method if it is found.

For a pure e4 application there is no default definition of cut/copy/paste commands and the `WidgetMethodHandler` is not available. SWT controls will  continue to support cut/copy/paste but there is no other support.

You can put text in the clipboard using something like:

```
Clipboard clipboard = new Clipboard(Display.getCurrent());

clipboard.setContents(new Object [] {"Text for clipboard"},
                      new Transfer [] {TextTransfer.getInstance()});

clipboard.dispose()
```

and get text from the clipboard with:

```
Clipboard clipboard = new Clipboard(Display.getCurrent());

String text = (String)clipboard.getContents(TextTransfer.getInstance());

clipboard.dispose()
```

Comment: This is probably due to my lack of Eclipse RCP knowledge and should probably be a separate question but I'm unsure how to link these handlers to my commands. If I don't configure a handler in `application.e4xmi` then the menu item is just grayed out when I run the RCP app, so I'm guessing I need to do something for the default handler to be used.

Comment: Sorry but you did not make it clear this is an e4 application (please use the tag [tag:e4] for that). There is no default copy/cut/paste support in a pure e4 application and the default handler shown here is not available. It is up to you to write it all.

Comment: Do you know of any well documented examples for writing a cut/copy/paste handler? Even a few pointers would be much appreciated.